# Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [simple_query_string]

Tags: elasticsearch

In elasticsearch 5.6.2 and 5.6.3 (Ubuntu 16.04), this query

```
GET _search
{
   "simple_query_string": {
      "query": "test1 + test2",
      "analyzer": "snowball",
      "fields": ["myfield"],
      "default_operator": "and"
   }
}
```

Is causing this error

```
{
   "error": {
      "root_cause": [
         {
            "type": "parsing_exception",
            "reason": "Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [simple_query_string].",
            "line": 2,
            "col": 44
         }
      ],
      "type": "parsing_exception",
      "reason": "Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [simple_query_string].",
      "line": 2,
      "col": 44
   },
   "status": 400
}
```

This is almost the same as the first example here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-simple-query-string-query.html

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 5):

You need to include the `simple_query_string` inside the `query` section, like this:

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "simple_query_string": {
      "query": "test1 + test2",
      "analyzer": "snowball",
      "fields": ["myfield"],
      "default_operator": "and"
    }
  }
}
```